# Pass infinity params as input to a generic

Tags: java, generics

is it possible to pass many param to a generic like varargs in java?
i mean,i want to have a generic that take many params instead this mode:

```
//A generic class for sample
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Setter
    @Getter
    public class RequestInfo<T,D> {
            private T param1;
            private D param2;

    }
```

Comment: Interesting. I'm also curious how you create an instance, if don't know exactly how much generics have.

Comment: Why you simply don't use `List<Object>` ?

Comment: this is a wrapper class for spring mvc controller to wrapp to params like two entities or some things else, together and send in @RequestBody.

Comment: @KunLun could you give me some details?

Comment: Request for clarification ... is there anything that could be added to one of the answers to make it accept-worthy?

Answer (score 5):

Here:

```
public class RequestInfo<T,D> {
        private T param1;
        private D param2;
```

The point of using generic types is ... to use them in your code. Thus, there is no real need (or sense) in having an **unknown** number of type parameters). You know each type parameter, because you intend to **use** it somewhere in your class further down.

And even when you **generate** code, that generator will know how many (different) types will be required prior generating that java class.

A vararg array, on the other hand, is *used* at runtime. You can write a loop that walks that array, no matter if the array has 0, 1, or 500 entries.

Meaning: varargs is A) syntactical sugar and B) mostly a "runtime" thing. Generics are almost the opposite of that. Generics add **type** information, to be used by the compiler, and well, mostly *erased* at runtime.

Comment: thanks,so,the main question is some times i want to wrapp two entities but some times i want two wrapp three entities!!

Comment: @soheilqalamkari Well, then your real question is maybe "how to generate such classes" efficiently?

Comment: well,it is a general idea for using of this types generic class.

Comment: @soheilqalamkari Besides the updates I made a few minutes ago, I cant think of much else what to say here. Generics arent meant to be used like "unknown count of them".

Comment: Both have to be resolved at compile time (think of calling an overloaded method with varargs) and both are used at run time. It would be nice to have a generic `Function` interface with variable parameters instead of having in the system library `Supplier`, `Function` and `BiFunction` only.

Comment: @soheilqalamkari Assuming a class has the methods `String foo(int i) { return "" + i; }` and `int foo(int... ints) { return ints.length; }`, then you will get a compile error for `int a = new Foo().foo(42);`, not first an error at run time. When using Java reflection (at run time), varargs are just arrays whereas [the actual type parameter can be accessed via Java reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/ParameterizedType.html) at run time. Therefore, if at all, _generics_ are more a _"runtime thing"_ than _varargs_.

Answer (score 1):

Such ***variable type parameters*** would be **thinkable, but** are **currently not supported** by Java.

It **would require** arrays or collections with **type declaration per element** and **fixed indexes** for **type checking at compile time**:

```
/* Fake variable type parameters syntax (non-valid Java code) */
public class RequestInfo<T...> {
    private T... params;

    public RequestInfo(T... params) {
        this.params = params;
    }

    public T[0] getFirstParameter() {
        return params[0];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RequestInfo<String, Integer> info = new RequestInfo("foo", 42);
        String param1 = info.getFirstParameter();
        Integer param2 = info.params[1];
    }

    // but...
    public T[?] /* <- compile error, because of unknown type */ getParameter(int i) {
        return params[i]; // <- compile error: 'i' unknown at compile time
    }
}
```

But as you can see in the [`java.util.function`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/package-summary.html) package, which contains interfaces for various number of type parameters, Java does **not support this yet and there are no plans to do so**. The further development of Java aims at performance improvements even if more code has to be written. For example, [Value Types](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/169) are planned which are more restrictive types that allow more memory-efficient arrays (see project [Valhalla](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/valhalla/)).

Comment: yes thats it!!! but it is not supported in java as you know.do you have any suggestion?

Comment: @soheilqalamkari The classes `RequestInfo2` with two type parameters, `RequestInfo3` with three type parameters, etc. up to a given upper limit might be generated, e.g. by [extending Lombok](https://www.baeldung.com/lombok-custom-annotation) (which you're obviously already using). The question is what is better in the long run: to maintain a larger code base or a smaller code base plus code generation code. Independent of that, you might propose your idea to the Lombok project.